# Is there a way to use the keyboard to move an application to another Space on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-spaces, virtual-desktop

I'm using Spaces on OS X, and I'd like to replicate the Ctrl-Alt-<arrow> functionality (or is it Ctrl-Alt-<arrow> -- I can never remember) in Gnome that causes the currently selected window to move to another virtual desktop.  This is far and away a more pleasant way of moving applications from desktop to desktop.

Is there a built-in way to do this?  How about some kind of applescript or Quicksilver trigger?  Third party app?  I'm willing to pay a small amount for an app that does this, so Free-as-in-beer is not required.

I am specifically NOT looking for a way to do this that requires using the mouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution: [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/), by Irradiated Software.  It has exactly what I want, plus a bunch of other fantastic keyboard shortcuts. It's not free ($13 USD) but it's a fantastic solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

There are some handy AppleScripts for spaces [here](http://soylentfoo.jnewland.com/articles/2007/11/22/spaces-application-assignments-and-applescript) including one that will move the front most window to a space of your choosing (will give you a dialog box).

You could just map the script to a keyboard shortcut, or alter the script so that it moves the window to a particular space, then create a new script and a shortcut for each space.

Answer (score 4):

[HyperSpaces](http://hyperspacesapp.com/) for Mac is a great utility for customizing Spaces. While it doesn't offer the functionality you're looking for, the developer explains why it's quite difficult to do so in [this thread](http://getsatisfaction.com/thecocoabots/topics/move_the_current_window_to_another_space_using_the_keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

This requires the mouse (which I know you don't want, but others might find it useful):

Hold the mouse button down on the window's title bar (as if you are going to drag it), and hit the Control+Number combination.  You'll go to that other space.  Then release the mouse button, and the window will be in that space.

Comment: This isn't what I needed, but it is an answer:  It's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found is [Spacey](http://most-advantageous.com/spacey/). It does exactly what you need and it's free.

Comment: Spacey seems to have stopped working in 10.7. The similar feature in Optimal Layout was also removed.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Andreas Hegenberg’s free [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) to do exactly this. Despite its name, it provides great keyboard shortcuts. And also, it all resides without the app bundle, so there is no deep tinkering with system files.

Comment: a great tool, but no longer free.  you should still get it, though.  if you use it much at all, it'll be worth a few bucks.

Answer (score 0):

Select the window you'd like, trigger the Spaces layout, and then press Control + Desktop number.  That might work even if you don't trigger the Spaces view.

Also, check System Preferences -> Mouse & Keyboard PrefPane -> Keyboard Shortcuts Tab.  I'm not at my Mac at the moment (WinXP only at work), but if there's shortcuts they should be in that list.

Comment: Sadly, no go.  Tried that, but all hitting a number does there is jump to that space

Comment: If you click the title bar of a window and then use the keyboard shortcut to change spaces the window will go along for the ride.