# move through spaces and take window with you without using a mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion, osx-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What keyboard shortcuts move, resize, and maximize windows under Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/68811/what-keyboard-shortcuts-move-resize-and-maximize-windows-under-mac-os-x)
>   [Move windows between Spaces in Mac OS X using only the keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/233246/move-windows-between-spaces-in-mac-os-x-using-only-the-keyboard)

I have just set up being able to navigate through spaces on lion without using the mouse. I want to know if one is able to, like in Ubuntu, move windows through windows with shortcut keys.

in Ubuntu it was something like

```
Shift > Cntrl > Arrow Direction
```

Isn't there a program to let me do this?

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of the first question, but here's more (cross-site) duplicates:
[2](http://superuser.com/questions/18537/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-keyboard-to-move-an-application-to-another-space-on-os?rq=1), [3](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28286/move-windows-around-a-desktop-and-to-different-desktops-using-only-the-key), [4](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1488/how-to-move-a-window-to-another-space-without-using-the-mouse)

Comment: @LauriRanta because of first recommendation `keyboard shortcut move`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from:
[What keyboard shortcuts move, resize, and maximize windows under Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/68811/what-keyboard-shortcuts-move-resize-and-maximize-windows-under-mac-os-x)

"Not built in, but you can install 3rd party software.

http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/26411/mercurymover

http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/30591/right-zoom
link|edit|flag

answered Nov 11 '09 at 4:45
ridogi"

Answer (score 0):

I have not Mac so I can't test it myself but it seems this user has did it and write an [article](http://jon.smajda.com/2007/06/30/keyboard-control-for-mac-os-x-windows/).

Or you can use third party tool for this like [mercurymover](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/26411/mercurymover).